# What is the Basic Latin character set used by ISO Standards Catalogue 01.140.10?

Tags: iso, iso-8859-1, character-set

I have a reference to "the Basic Latin character set used by ISO Standards Catalogue 01.140.10" and I need to know the exact set of code points.

Without going through all the standards found in [Standards Catalogue 01.140.10](https://www.iso.org/ics/01.140.10/x/) can I find this Basic Latin character set somewhere (preferably reasonably authoritative)?

Is it "Latin-1", ISO 8859-1, etc.? Or something entirely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `LATIN-1` is the `ISO-8859-1` character set.

Here's an "authorative" link from ISO web site, although it seems you have to buy it:

https://www.iso.org/standard/28245.html

I would be comfortable taking any of the links from wikipedia or google search as authorative (take your pick):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)

http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/iso8859-1.html

https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html

Comment: Sorry if it seems nit-picking. Isn't this something different from "basic Latin"? I think that includes only the letters, not the punctuation?

Comment: This is definitely the "basic latin" character set, since this character set forms the basis of other character sets that extend it. Im also not aware of any character set without the puntuation. I'm 100% sure this is the one they are referring to.